# How to fix the Inconsistency in the scrollbar for windows and Mac

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, scroll

I have a HTML table with fixed head and the body have the vertical scroll bar when the max-height exceeds. i have used `overflow-y: scroll;` to achieve this. it works fine but i noticed that the scrollbar design looks different in Windows Chrome and Mac Chrome. In Windows Chrome the scrollbar takes up around 17px and due to which the last column layout is broken as shown below. In Mac the scrollbar doesnt take up the space as its displayed while scrolling and it doesn’t take up space. Due to this i have Inconsistency in Mac and Windows.

[image]

In my Mac system preferences *Show scroll bars* option is set like below.

[image]

is there any way to fix this inconsistency with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom css to get desired results. ie.

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
```